# How to store in a @State the status if LongPressGesture has been used

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

```
@State var longPressUsed = false

var body: some View {
    var longPress: some Gesture {
        LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 2)
            .updating($revealTip) { currentstate, gestureState, transaction in
                (1) self.longPressUsed = true
            }
            .onEnded(finished in 
                (2) self.longPressUsed = true
            }
    }

}
```

How do I register long-press usages excluding repeated? Placing it in (1) leads to a warning that state variables should not be touched when the view is changing. When placed in (2), the code is not always called.

Answer (score 1):

Use *only* `.onEnded`, it is called when really *long* press is detected

```
var longPress: some Gesture {
    LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 2)
        .onEnded { _ in 
            self.longPressUsed = true
        }
}
```

Comment: This is what I suspected. But the animation starts way earlier, so how do I capture the fact that the animation has already started and revealed hidden element to the user?